# Download an Image from web and pass it as keys of python -selenium to a file field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download a file from web using python requests and then passing this file to python-selenium webdriver keys to an HTML file field. My current code for this is as follow.

```
image = requests.get('https://theartgalleryumd.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/dsc0017.jpg')
i = Image.open(StringIO(image.content))

image_name = "{0}_file_name.jpg".format(unicode(time.time()),)
image = i.save(os.getcwd()+"/{0}".format(image_name))

driver.find_element_by_id('image').send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/{0}".format(image_name))
```

This code is working but I think there will be much better ways to do it. and is it possible to assign the file / image to a file field in python selenium without saving /  creating it on the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly. The `input` element with `type="file"` requires a local path to the file to be passed in. This means that you have to download the file first and have it saved on a disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `urlretrieve` instead of a series of `PIL` commands to download the image and save it:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('https://theartgalleryumd.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/dsc0017.jpg')
```